# Terminology for the natural field associated to a prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology

Consider a commutative ring R with a prime ideal P.
Is there a terminology or name for the field of fractions of the R/P in the literature? I suspect that "function field of P" is not a correct term.

My second question is there any standard (or at least widely used) notation for this field in the literature?

Comment: Residue field is a pretty common term for this.

Comment: You mean $P$ is a maximal ideal so that $R/P$ is a field (when $R$ is a Dedekind domain every prime ideals are maximal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually called the "residue field" at $P$, and is often denoted $k(P)$.  Both the term and the notation are also used more generally for the corresponding notion when $P$ is a point in a scheme (or more generally a locally ringed space).

Comment: What is k in k(P)? An abbreviation for "Körper"? Is the notation k(P) also used in the situation where R is not necessarily a k-algebra? If this is the case, I think this completely answers my question.

Comment: Yeah, $k$ here is just used in the sense of "field".  It isn't referring to any particular field that $R$ is an algebra over.